# How to get access to phpmyadmin interface

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've got a probleme with phpmyadmin on ubuntu 16.4
i did the installation step by step and when i'm trying to get access 'localhost\phpmyadmin\' i have white page with a long scipt in php.
i want to get the phpmyadmin interface with the login and passord request.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it unprocessed code? What installation? Phpmyadmin is a php application. You need to be able to serve php pages to use it

Comment: it's php info page. i followed this : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: What does that script show?